# Losing my working tree with git aliases

Tags: git, windows-7

I've been running into this error whenever I try to use some of my git aliases.

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-am cannot be used without a working tree.
```

In particular my "git sync $1"

```
sync => !f() { git checkout $1 && git pull && git checkout - && git rebase $1 && git push --force origin HEAD;}; f
```

If I do each of those commands separately it works flawlessly. This alias has worked for quite some time, but occasionally fails. Google has been rather desperate for information regarding losing your working tree.

Any insight? Thanks in advance.